# Animate.css without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animate.css

I am trying to make animation on page scrolling.

I use the Animate.css library.

The documentation only shows how to use it with jQuery, but I'm currently learning how to use Vanilla Javascript. I was trying to use window.pageYOffset but that only works when the browser reaches the container and not when it is revealed by the scroll.

Answer (score 3):

Another example of vanilla JS animation without jQuery (or any other libraries).

```js
var v = 0;
var delta = 1;
function verticalMove() {
    redBox = document.getElementById('verticalDiv')
    v += delta;
    redBox.style.top = v + "px";
    if (v <= 0) delta = 1;
    if (v >= 50) delta = -1;
}
function startMove(event) {
    setInterval(verticalMove, 30);
    event.target.onclick="";
}
```

```css
.verticalDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="verticalDiv" id="verticalDiv" onclick="startMove(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example how you can animate without jQuery. Investigate the MDN doc page `window.onscroll` for the scroll event.

```
const $item = document.querySelector('.starred-item');
$item && ($item.classList.add('animated', 'bounce'));
```